# CMake : Relink directory and double linking

Tags: cmake

In one of my projects at work the following was noticed and asked to me.
A binary would link and then link again in a folder called the "Relink" folder.
I also checked and the binary is in two places and linking occurs twice.

CMAKE version used is 2.6 - patch 2.

I found that in the build folder, the generated cmake_install.cmake has the following entry

```
        IF(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" MATCHES "^(Unspecified)$")
      IF("${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}" MATCHES "^([Dd][Ee][Bb][Uu][Gg])$")
        FILE(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin" TYPE EXECUTABLE FILES "/path/to/binary/file/folder/CMakeFiles/CMakeRelink.dir/<binary name>").....
```

If INSTALL is used in CMAKE, and COMPONENT is not created with the install command AND the build is a Debug build, then this Relink Folder is created and the binary is linked twice. The question is why does this happen?
Linking twice increases your over build time.
So what purpose does this serve.
If the Install command is omitted or the build is a Debug build, then this does not occur.
Why not and why is it relevant if the build is a Debug build or not?
I have searched documentation and this site but could not find an explanation.

example output :

```
.....
Linking CXX shared library lib<library-name>.so  <==  Linking the first time
[100%] Built target <another library name>
[ 15%] Built target <another-library-name1>
[ 92%] Built target <another-library-name2>
[ 92%] Built target <another-library-name3>
[100%] Built target <another-library-name4>
[100%] Built target <another-library-name5>
Linking CXX shared library CMakeFiles/CMakeRelink.dir/lib<library-name>.so  <== Second linking.
```

This Relink directory shows up when the following CMAKELists entry is added

```
install(TARGETS <binary/library name>
        RUNTIME
        DESTINATION "bin")
```

So building this as a Debug build and non COMPONENT install shows this behaviour.
Same code when built on Jenkins does not have this because the Jenkins build is a Release/Optimized build and not a Debug build.

Comment: Please create a minimal working example that shows your problem. I never had the problem described in your question.

Comment: Hi. I updated the text to give more details with sample output, removing library names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Relinking before installation of binaries has a lot to do with preserving the RPATH in the build.

So I tried to fulfill the initial check for COMPONENT definition and then saw the generated CMake and it shows new conditions to fulfill.
Found some relevant info here
http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011377.html

So, in the test project where the COMPONENT building is enabled, for INSTALL command of cmake, Re-linking again occurs with another condition to fulfill this time. In this case install_public option is checked, which has been enabled in the project.

```
IF(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" MATCHES "^(install_public)$")
IF("${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}" MATCHES "^([Dd][Ee][Bb][Uu][Gg])$")
    FILE(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib64" TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY       

#install CMakeRelink.dir/<library_name>.so.<library_version> ......
```

Some info here as well in the docs
https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_2.8.0_Docs

Search for Re-linking in the above link.
So I tested another build by changin the CMAKELists.txt and setting CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH to OFF in the application CMAKEList. 
This also stopped the double linking.